# MySQL select row dateandtime > NOW

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create a cron job involving aggregating emails sent within a period.

I need to perform a query such as

```
SELECT count(*) from table where action_time < NOW();
```

How would I go about this?

I'm aware of `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` but I need to compare both the time and date so the action is performed in the exact minute after the event, `CURTIME` would mean at midnight i would get an issue.

Edit: `CURTIME()` only includes the time so a job in the db with action time 23:59:59 wouldn't be run at 00:00:59 - a minute later (since the latter is not greater than the first)

I can use datetime or timestamp but what would I use as a function to compare (I use NOW() above but that doesn't work)

Update: I tried using
SELECT count(*) from table where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_time) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
and it works :)

Comment: What data type is `action_time`, it should be `DATETIME`.

Comment: it is datetime though im thinking of using TIMESTAMP to make it more comparable as Mchl suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
SELECT count(*) from table where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_time) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

`CURTIME()` and `NOW()` both actually return current time to the second. `NOW()` returns the date part too. Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: The issue is CURTIME() doesn't include the date, im not sure, so if i have a cron running every minute a job aimed for 11:59:59 wouldn't run at 00:00:59 because the later is not greater than the first

Comment: Sorry i mean a job with action_time of 11:59:59 wouldn't run when the cron is run at the next period

Comment: I see now (I think). What you should do, is to store in DB when was the last cron job performed (using both date and time), and have your query compare to that time instead of NOW()

Comment: I edited my question with slightly more clarity. I could look at that  there has to be a way to do it though its so simple. Maybe i should look at storing it as a unix timestamp

Comment: Just storing it as mysql's TIMESTAMP will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the timestamp from mysql and compare with the time from your *nix evironment.